# How to use dictionary in Python correctly

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, dictionary

Python dictionaries have always confused me.

I have 3 dictionaries:

```
left_dict = {"N":"W", "W":"S", "S":"E", "E":"N"}
right_dict = {"N":"E", "E":"S", "S":"W", "W":"N"}
turn_dict = {"N":"S", "E":"W", "S":"N", "W":"E"}
```

I have a class Robot which is initialized as such:

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, team, x, y, direction):
        self.team = team
        self.health = 50
        self.x = x     
        self.y = y
        self.direction = direction
```

In this class I have a method that changes the direction.

```
def left90(self):
        self.direction = left_dict <---- **is this how I would change the direction**
```

Comment: I created the dictionaries... It's the implementation that I don't know how to do. I know what they are used for.. it's how they are used I don't know how to do.

Comment: I'm just asking if the last line is the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
def left90(self):
    self.direction = left_dict[self.direction]
```